# What's the symbolism of the Cid's beard?

Tags: meaning, poetry, symbolism, spanish-language, cantar-de-mio-cid

The book *El "Cantar de Mio Cid" y la épica medieval española* by Alan Deyermond, at page 37, mentions

> el simbolismo de la barba del Cid

that is, "the symbolism of the Cid's beard", but such a symbol is not explained. I know that the author of the poem mention several times the long beard of the Cid, but I don't know what's the symbolism conveyed in such kind of expressions. It has maybe something to do with maturity? Could anyone explain it?

Comment: You are referring to the book by Alan Deyermond?

Comment: Yes, sorry, @ClaraDiazSanchez: I forgot to write this in my post.